sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper[CasinoPlayer(casino_players)] or this Session
I'm developing an application using FastAPI and I'm using SQLAlchemy to interact with a PostgreSQL database. In my code, I'm encountering the error sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper[CasinoPlayer(casino_players)] or this Session, and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.
Here's my code
main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Base
from typing import List
from schemas import Player, PlayerInfo
from managers import PlayerManager

url = URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql",
    host="localhost",
    port=5432,
    database="casino_player",
    username="postgres",
    password="postgres"
)

engine = create_engine(url)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI(title="Casino Players", version="1.0.0")

player_manager = PlayerManager()


@app.post("/add_player/", response_model=Player)
def add_player(name: str, win_value: float, casino_name: str):
    player = Player(name=name, win_value=win_value, casino_name=casino_name)
    db_player = player_manager.add_player(player)
    return Player(id=db_player.id, name=db_player.name, win_value=db_player.win_value, casino_name=db_player.casino_name)


@app.get("/player/{player_id}", response_model=PlayerInfo)
def get_player_info(player_id: int):
    db_player = player_manager.get_player(player_id)
    win_value_formatted = f"{db_player.win_value} $"
    return PlayerInfo(id=db_player.id, name=db_player.name, win_value=win_value_formatted, casino_name=db_player.casino_name)


@app.get("/all_players/", response_model=List[PlayerInfo])
def get_all_players_info():
    players_info_list = player_manager.get_all_players_info()
    return players_info_list


@app.put("/player/{player_id}")
def update_player(player_id: int, name: str, win_value: float, casino_name: str):
    player_manager.update_player(player_id, name, win_value, casino_name)
    return {"message": "Інформація про гравця оновлена"}


@app.delete("/player/{player_id}")
def delete_player(player_id: int):
    player_manager.delete_player(player_id)
    return {"message": "Гравця успішно видалено"}


@app.delete("/all_players/")
def delete_all_players():
    num_deleted = player_manager.delete_all_players()
    return {"message": f"Всі гравці видалені, всього {num_deleted} записів"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, log_level="info")


managers.py
from typing import List, Type
from fastapi import HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from models import CasinoPlayer
from schemas import Player, PlayerInfo


class PlayerManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()

    def add_player(self, player: Player) -> CasinoPlayer:
        with self.session as session:
            db_player = CasinoPlayer(name=player.name, win_value=player.win_value, casino_name=player.casino_name)
            session.add(db_player)
            session.commit()
            return db_player

    def get_player(self, player_id: int) -> Type[CasinoPlayer]:
        with self.session as session:
            try:
                return session.query(CasinoPlayer).filter_by(id=player_id).one()
            except:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Гравця з таким ID не знайдено")

    def get_all_players_info(self) -> List[PlayerInfo]:
        with self.session as session:
            players_info_list = []
            players_records = session.query(CasinoPlayer).all()
            for player in players_records:
                win_value_formatted = f"{player.win_value} $"
                players_info_list.append(PlayerInfo(id=player.id, name=player.name, win_value=win_value_formatted, casino_name=player.casino_name))
            return players_info_list

    def update_player(self, player_id: int, new_name: str, new_win_value: float, new_casino_name: str):
        with self.session as session:
            db_player = self.get_player(player_id)
            db_player.name = new_name
            db_player.win_value = new_win_value
            db_player.casino_name = new_casino_name
            session.commit()

    def delete_player(self, player_id: int):
        with self.session as session:
            db_player = self.get_player(player_id)
            session.delete(db_player)
            session.commit()

    def delete_all_players(self) -> int:
        with self.session as session:
            players_records = session.query(CasinoPlayer).all()
            num_deleted = 0
            for player in players_records:
                session.delete(player)
                num_deleted += 1
            session.commit()
            return num_deleted

schemas.py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PositiveInt, PositiveFloat


class Player(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[PositiveInt] = None
    name: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=50, description="Прізвище, Ім'я, По-батькові")
    win_value: PositiveFloat
    casino_name: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=50, description="Назва казино")


class PlayerInfo(BaseModel):
    id: PositiveInt
    name: str
    win_value: str
    casino_name: str



models.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class CasinoPlayer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "casino_players"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    win_value = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    casino_name = Column(String, nullable=False)

I suspect the error is related to an incorrect binding of the session with my database engine or with the CasinoPlayer model. How can I fix this error and properly configure the SQLAlchemy session to work with FastAPI?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Although you are creating Session with sessionmaker, you are importing Session from sqlalchemy.orm inside your manager

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
